# Kubernetes wordpress to mysql connection issue

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Wordpress pod that doesn't connect to my SQL DB pod.  The wordpress mysql deployment is called wordpress-mysql so the referencing is correct. This is the message that appears.

> Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
>
> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22
>
> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22
>
> MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known

This is the code for the wordpress.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:

    app: wordpress
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: wp-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: do-block-storage


---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.example.services
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: web

---



---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: wordpress:4.8-apache
        name: wordpress
        env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: wordpress-mysql
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-pass
              key: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: wordpress
        volumeMounts:
        - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wp-pv-claim
```

The following is an output from kubectl get services

```
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
frontend          ClusterIP   10.245.131.56   <none>        80/TCP     4m25s
kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.245.0.1      <none>        443/TCP    9m46s
wordpress-mysql   ClusterIP   None            <none>        3306/TCP   5m16s
```

MySQL Service YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: mysql
  clusterIP: None
```

Comment: Haven;t you created k8s service for `wordpress-mysql` I don't see cluster-ip set in your `kubectl get services` output.

Comment: It has been created, but it doesn't have a cluster. I have updated the question with the service detail

Comment: Why have you set clusterIP as None for  wordpress-mysql service?

Comment: That's what the K8s article recommends: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/

Comment: `clusterIP: None` explicitly makes it unreachable from other services.  You don't want that here.

Comment: how do I set it so it assigns the cluster IP?

Comment: turns out there was an issue with kube-dns not working. Once resolved this was fine

Comment: @DavidMaze this is wrong. Kubernetes will properly resolve by service names (in this particular case everything should be deployed in the same namespace, otherwise service names should just include namespace and cluster.local).

Comment: Aha, if you specify `clusterIP: None` there is no cluster-internal load balancer but [there are DNS records that point directly at the pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#with-selectors).  (So it _is_ reachable, contrary to my comment above, thanks.)

Comment: Ok as @EgorStambakio pointed out the cluster IP should be set to none. I've resolve the issue which required a cluster rebuild, for some reason my Kube DNS service was running with errors. This now works fine. I also explicitly labelled the fronted and backend separately so there were no selector issues